# How to get message from method

Tags: scala, recursion, scala-cats, for-comprehension

I want to rewrite console IO application (sum counting) to messenger-bot. The `StdIn.readLine()` let me get the next input number in recursion.

```
object HelloCountBot extends TelegramBot with Polling with Commands {
  def go(number: Long, chatId: Long): IO[Long] =
    for {
      input <- ??? /*here I need get the next number*/
      acc <- input.toLong match {
        case 0L => sendMessageMethodIO(chatId, "The sum is:") *> IO(0L)
        case _ => go(number + 1, chatId)
      }
      acc <- IO(acc + input.toLong)
    } yield acc

  /*input point for every new message*/
  override def onMessage(message: Message) = message.text match {
    case Some(text) if text == "start" => go(1, message.chat.id)
      .unsafeRunSync
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = HelloCountBot.run()
}
```

How to organize code to get the next message inside recursion from method onMessage with Unit return.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, just updated! The problem is how to get next number inside the recursion in ```go``` method, but every new number comes to ```onMessage``` method, which also starts recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find in https://github.com/bot4s/telegram any methods for receiving messages in the way that you want. So I think the best option is to create stateful bot as shown in this example: https://github.com/bot4s/telegram/blob/master/examples/src/StatefulBot.scala.

So if I understand your code correctly, it can be reorganized in the following way (trait `PerChatState` is taken from the link above):

```
object HelloCountBot
  extends TelegramBot
    with Polling
    with Commands
    with PerChatState[Long] {

  override def onMessage(message: Message): Future[Unit] = {

    implicit val msg = message

    message.text match {
      case Some(text) if text == "start" =>
        Future {
          setChatState(0L)
        }
      case Some(value) if value == "0" =>
        withChatState {
          sum =>
            reply(s"The sum is ${sum.getOrElse(0L)}")
              .map(_ => clearChatState)
        }

      case Some(value) =>
        withChatState {
          mayBeSum =>
            Future {
              mayBeSum.foreach(
                sum => setChatState(sum + value.toLong)
              )
            }
        }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = HelloCountBot.run()
}
```

It uses Futures, but you can rewrite it to IO, if you prefer.